# RIP Yaphet Kotto (Alien, The Running Man, etc.)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Yaphet Kotto died on March 15, 2021 at the age of 81. A perennial supporting actor, Kotto had multiple prominent sci-fi/genre roles, including Parker in *Alien* and the video game spin-off *Alien: Isolation*, William Laughlin in *The Running Man*, Doc in *Freddy's Dead: The Final Nightmare*, and Mr. Big in the James Bond film *Live and Let Die*. An actor who always brought some esteem the films he was in, his presence in the sci-fi community will be missed.

[image: Yaphet Kotto]

Comment: Sorry to hear this.  I remember him mostly from "Homicide: Life on the Street".

Comment: Discovered today that he was in the running to play Jean-Luc Picard! https://www.joblo.com/movie-news/yaphet-kotto-star-trek-picard-role

Comment: And also _Midnight Run_ ...